# utf-8 encoding in DOMDocument class

Tags: php, javascript, dom, utf-8

I am using PHP's DOMDocument class to open an HTML file, make some changes, and save it. The problem is that the javascript in every page that is loaded, contains utf 8 characters, and when I save the HTML file, these characters are "changed". Here's my code.

```
$doc=new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile($path);

$doc->encoding='UTF-8';
$doc->saveHTMLFile($path);
```

The file is saved again but the special characters gets distorted. e.g if my javascript had an image path set to `french/Comment ça s’écrit/` , this becomes `french/Comment&ensp;&ccedil;a&ensp;s&rsquo;&eacute;crit&ensp;` . The wierd thing is that this only happens to my javascript paths, the html elements dont get changed and are in the correct encoding.

Comment: what happen if the javascript is in some CDATA block?

Comment: sorry dint check it!! the thing is i do hav to change javascript sometimes like adding new methods..

Comment: I dont understand the role Javascript plays in this? Can you explain and give examples please. Thanks.

Comment: @Gordon: I think he is generating some static pages using PHP.

Comment: yes i am kind of...I have got like 800 web pages that i need to change slightly, and for that i was using this php script.

Comment: please provide a reproducable test case. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try placing your javascript between CDATA tags as shown below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
    // your javascript here
/*]]>*/
</script>
```